# Use user info without prompt or confirm?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I want to do is be able to do is have users submit info and be able to use it - without using prompt.

I would like to have them be able to input and have a different box to be able to give them info based on there info. I.E. 81 is a great number.

```
var c = prompt("pick a number")
if(c>100){
  console.log("110 is to high of a number") 
}
```

This is what I have. I'm used to JavaScript editors and using `console.log`. I'm looking for a way to do that based on info I receive and be able to give feed back in a different `<div>` or whatever. Can anyone help?

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

function showConfirmationDialog() {
  var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  alert(textbox.value + '\n' + location.value);
}
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="showConfirmationDialog();" />
```

Comment: [Welcome to the wonderful world of jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) ... Also, `$("#textbox")` is the same as `document.getElementById('textbox');` in jQuery. See [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I don't see where the `#textbox` and `#location` elements are located.  Not included in the example?

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can use a click handler that looks like this:

```
$('#someButton').click(function () {
    var val = $('#inputFieldId').val();
    var $outputDiv = $('#outputFieldId');
    var msg = '';
    if (! $.isNumeric(val)) {
        msg = 'Please enter a valid number';
    }
    else if (parseInt(val, 10) > 100) {
        msg = 'Enter number less than 100';        
    }
    else {
        msg = 'Thank you for the wonderful number: ' + val;
    }
    $outputDiv.text(msg);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd9wv/) that shows the above code in action.

Comment: thank you very much!!! question say i wanted 3 boxes like the one you had, and wanted to add the numbers up and give a  input based on that? can i add say in the html <input id="number2"  type="text"/> ext ext..then in the js msg = 'Thank you for the wonderful number: ' + (val+va+v);... if you would not mind explaining a little..is val is holding the input. example http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/jBqVn/

Comment: and ty everyone else...you guys are the best! it one thing to learn this..but to use it is completely different. learned js first and am still learning jQuery...i can do with i want just using js and prompts...but i want to box for the answers to be imputed...and a box to give a message

Comment: ty very much...np whenever you have time! i put this in here with just js to give a better idea of what i am trying to do...i would like to be able to do the same without prompts and have boxes for the info to be submited.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/philyphil/DwCRh

Comment: @philly - Here's a ridiculously over the top, tutorialized version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwCRh/2/).

Comment: thank you very much!!! your the man!!! exactly what i was looking for...was going crazy trying to figure it out!!!

Comment: @philly - Glad I could help.  Please try to read some of the documentation I mentioned so you can understand what your code does. In general, you should read documentation on your own to learn this stuff.  I just figured I'd throw you a bone since I was bored ;-)

Comment: i have been trying to learn. been at this for 4 months. mainly js.For this problem i was looking for 2 days i understand the code, and thank you for including the comments. my problem was mainly with connecting the html, js,  jquery. i can use them all separate.

Comment: Sorry jahroy still new. Did not know about accpeting answers. Just acpeted your answer...Thanks again!

Comment: Right on. You're very welcome.  Welcome to StackOverflow!  You're sure to learn a ton around here if you stick around.  I know I have!